# Is there a mistake in my evaluation of $\int\frac{3x+1}{\sqrt{5x^2+1}}dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration

I want to evaluate the following integral:

> $$\int\frac{3x+1}{\sqrt{5x^2+1}}dx$$

The answer given in my textbook is $\frac{3}{5}\sqrt{5x^2+1}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\ln(x\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{5x^2+1})$.

I think the author has excess factor $\sqrt{5}$ in logarithm.

My solution is

$$\begin{align}
\int\frac{3x+1}{\sqrt{5x^2+1}}dx &= \frac{3}{2}\int\frac{d(x^2)}{\sqrt{5x^2+1}}+\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{5x^2+1}}dx \\[6pt]
&=\frac{3}{\sqrt{5}}\sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{5}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\ln\left(x+\sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{5}}\right)
\end{align}$$

since 
$$\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2+a}}=\ln\left(x+\sqrt{x^2+a}\right)$$

Am I right?

N.B. Just to be short I skipped additive constant in antiderivatives, so don't mention it.

Comment: Your answers differ precisely by an additive constant, namely $\ln(\sqrt{5}) / \sqrt{5}$.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derive+%5Cfrac%7B3%7D%7B5%7D%5Csqrt%7B5x%5E2%2B1%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B%5Csqrt%7B5%7D%7D%5Cln(x%5Csqrt%7B5%7D%2B%5Csqrt%7B5x%5E2%2B1%7D)

Comment: this is really funny that we should not mention the reason of the difference between these expressions

Comment: WolframAlpha would have us believe that the textbook is correct: [here][1]


  [1]: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5B(3x%2B1)%2FSqrt%5B5x%5E2%2B1%5D,x%5D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**hint for another approach**

Put $$x=\frac {\sinh (t)}{\sqrt {5}} $$

then it becomes

$$\frac {1}{\sqrt {5}}\int \frac { \frac {3\sinh (t)}{\sqrt {5}}+1}{\cosh (t)}\cosh (t)dt $$

$$=\frac {3}{5}\cosh (t)+\frac {t}{\sqrt {5}}+C $$

Comment: Nice done, this is really an elegant way...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all comments, the difference between two forms was exactly in additive constant. My problem is solved and answered now.